# Regex to get out of a 10 character string (numbers and text) the first 4 or 5 characters

Tags: regex, character, capture-group

What i intended to do is: getting a 4-5 characters string(Usually meaning country and the city) out a pattern of 10 characters string. There are multiple instances of this.

```
    TEST IC ITMI12CR01 GRATH1CR01, ALTIR1AB02
TEST-ICITMI12CR01 BE5253, BE2178 and BE40035 towards GRATH1CR01, ROTIM1CR01 and ALTIR1AB02 are down
TEST-IC Multiple links are TRIST1AB01<><>ROTIM1CR01<>GRATH1CR01<>ITMI12CR01
TEST IC ITMI12CR01 links to GRATH1CR01, ALTIR1AB02
```

Taking one of the examples above: ITMI12CR01 and ROTIM1CR01.
For the first instance: It would get the 10 chars string get the first 4 characters into a capture group
Second instance: Get the first 5 characters into a capture group.

Do you think that this request is reasonable?

Thanks!

Comment: So it's 10-character strings consisting of alphanumeric characters not necessarily separated by spaces (for example, `TRIST1AB01<><>ROTIM1CR01<>GRATH1CR01<>ITMI12CR01` are 4 such strings)? And can you show us what you have done so far to try to solve this?

Comment: My approach initially is to get the 10 chars and do the 4-5 char extraction afterwards:
\b(?<site>[A-Z0-9]{10})+\b

but wanted to see if i could do this. As such i tried an approach of non-capturing group of 10 chars but inside capturing the 4-5 chars.
\b(?<site>([A-Z]{5}|[A-Z]{4})[A-Z0-9]{5}|[A-Z]{5})+\b

but no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should directly find either the 4 or 5-character match. If I have misunderstood what you are looking for, please clarify.

```
import re

s = """TEST IC ITMI12CR01 GRATH1CR01, ALTIR1AB02
TEST-ICITMI12CR01 BE5253, BE2178 and BE40035 towards GRATH1CR01, ROTIM1CR01 and ALTIR1AB02 are down
TEST-IC Multiple links are TRIST1AB01<><>ROTIM1CR01<>GRATH1CR01<>ITMI12CR01
TEST IC ITMI12CR01 links to GRATH1CR01, ALTIR1AB02"""


l = [match.group(1) if match.group(1) else match.group(2)
     for match in re.finditer(r'\b(?:([A-Z]{4})(?:[0-9][A-Z0-9]{5})|([A-Z]{5})(?:[0-9][A-Z0-9]{4}))\b', s)
    ]
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['ITMI', 'GRATH', 'ALTIR', 'GRATH', 'ROTIM', 'ALTIR', 'TRIST', 'ROTIM', 'GRATH', 'ITMI', 'ITMI', 'GRATH', 'ALTIR']
```

I am looking for either:

1. 4 alpha characters followed by 1 numeric followed by 5 alphanumeric characters or.
2. 5 alpha characters followed by 1 numeric followed by 4 alphanumeric characters.

[See Demo](http://ideone.com/if23Fx)

Comment: That's the stuff! Didn't think of it that way! Thanks!